# What am I missing with Weapon Infusion in Elden Ring?

Tags: elden-ring

So I just got back into Elden Ring, and am re-acquainting myself with the weapon upgrades/infusion systems.

I'm playing a Dex build, and am currently wielding the base dual-scimitars. However, when I look at the [Max Upgrades](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Scimitar) table, the Standard +25 has an Attack Power of 259 (with a D/C scaling), but a Keen +25 only has 222 (with an E/A scaling).

I don't quite understand what's going on here... does the AP not account for scaling? If so, what is AP based on, and why does infusion affect it?

Comment: Isn't that just because it would be too overpowered if it was 259+E/A scaling? I assume that'd make additional AP given by the scaling would be 222+~220 ish (if you're on str 20+dex 40), and D/C would be 259+~150 ish (same stat, str 20+dex 40)  so that would still make keen one to have more AP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AP shown here is the BASE attack power. So indeed before / without scaling.

Scaling depends on your current stats, so charts online will usually not show the end results.

Weapon infusion has always worked like in the DS series, you take a hit of base power to increase the scaling. With a dex build, the infusion should still net you an increase in your resulting AP unless you are really low level.